# how to get token data in gift warehouse

Tags: javascript, discord

How to get the URL link of the Gift that is on the token in my data does not write anything

```
 async function checkTokenValidityForToken(token, agentPool) {
    const cleanedToken = token.trim();
    const agent = agentPool[Math.floor(Math.random() * agentPool.length)];
  
    try {
      const [response, gifturl] = await Promise.all([
        axios.get('https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: cleanedToken,
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json'
          },
          httpsAgent: agent
        }),
        axios.get('https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/entitlements/gifts?locale=en', {
          headers: {
            Authorization: cleanedToken,
          },
          httpsAgent: agent
        }),
      ]);

      console.log(gifturl)
    } catch (error) {
      invalidTokens.push(cleanedToken);
      tokenCounter++;
    }
  }
```

I tried to use https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me/outbound-promotions/codes did not help the bot writes the token to a non-valid one and skips